# How to use setup method in moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moqcontrib

I can try to understand Moq and  how does it work? When we should use setup method? In my opinion,its documentation is too poor.Anyway. I want to share my code and what I wanted to do.

**Class under test.**

```
  public interface IProduct
{
    bool GiveCard();
    float CalculateDiscount(decimal price, decimal discount);
}

   public class Product : IProduct
   {
    private IProduct _product;
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int StockCount { get; set; }
    public float Discount { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }

    public float CalculateDiscount(decimal price, decimal discount)
    {
        var discountedPrice = (price * discount) / 100;
        Discount = price - discountedPrice;
        return price - discountedPrice;
    }

     public bool GiveCard()
    {
        return CalculateDiscount(Price, Discount) > 300;
    }
```

}

**Unit Test Class*

```
[Test]
    public void GiveCard_DiscountedAmountGreaterThanOrEqual300_ReturnTrue()
    {
        var mockObject = new Mock<IProduct>();
        var productService = new Product(mockObject.Object);

        mockObject.Setup(x => x.CalculateDiscount(450, 20)).Returns(360);
        var result = productService.GiveCard();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

I get 0 as a Result although I setted calculation result to the Discount property in CalculateDiscount() method .

Comment: "Class under test" actually is not class. Please provide class

Comment: The arguments have to match for Moq to use the method. The answer by alerya should work but [here is a little more information](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)

Comment: `mockObject.Setup(x => x.CalculateDiscount(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(360);` probably enough for your problem. However, your question does not give enough information. For example, what does `productService.GiveCard()` and when `IProduct.CalculateDiscount(float , float )` function is called?

Comment: @AdemCatamak I think that I gave enough info. GiveCard method is called when discount is applied to the product. GiveCard() method gives a card when total price equal or greater than 300. Codes say everything.Just  read please carefully.

Comment: I cannot see parameterless GiveCard method and I cannot see ProductService class. I want to give you proper help, thus; if you can supply more information, you can get more clear answers.

Comment: @AdemCatamak check it please. I added some information.

Comment: _product object CalculateDiscount method is not used above. Hence, your mock object's setup does not get hit. You can try to this in your `Product` class: `public bool GiveCard() { return _product.CalculateDiscount(Price, Discount) > 300; } `. In this case, given mock object CalculateDiscount method get hit and return 360 for you. (if  you use still setup like that : `mockObject.Setup(x => x.CalculateDiscount(450, 20)).Returns(360);` you should supply productService.Price as 450 and productService.Discount as 20

Comment: @AdemCatamak thanks. It has worked fine.You can answer question and I will accept as true answer it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`_product` object `CalculateDiscount` method is not used above. Hence, your mock object's setup does not get hit. You can try to this in your Product class:

```
public bool GiveCard()
{
    return _product.CalculateDiscount(Price, Discount) > 300;
}
```

In this case, given mock object CalculateDiscount method get hit and return 360 for you.

if you use still setup like that : `mockObject.Setup(x => x.CalculateDiscount(450, 20)).Returns(360);`, you should supply `productService.Price` as 450 and `productService.Discount` as 20

Note: you can also assert that mockObject function get hit or not:

```
mockObject.Verify(mock => mock.CalculateDiscount(450,20), Times.Once());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  mockObject.Setup(x => x.CalculateDiscount(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(360);
```